# star-shaped and linear-shaped query

Tags: sql, database

I was reading a paper discussing Query optimization. In the paper, the author gave a query example and mentioned that this query is star shaped. The query is as following:

```
SELECT last, first, dept
FROM nodes a, depts b, 
WHERE a.nodename = 'VM'
AND b.depname = 'DB2'
AND a.nodeid = c.nodeid
```

My question is: how to tell if a query is star-shaped or linear-shaped?

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: star shaped might mean it it's being run against a star schema, or takes the same form, which is ONE transaction type table joining to many other lookup type tables, with all of the lookup tables being one to many cardinality. I've never heard of star vs linear though.